# Is there an English idiom for 'your silence implies your consent'?

Tags: idioms

I was asked an interesting question today, is there an English equivalent of the saying *Zwijgen is instemmen*, that is "since you didn't answer, then you agreed with me".

I could not come up with any good example; although I could think of a few similar, but not quite the same, including the following:

- I'll take that as a 'yes' then.
- I don't hear any No's.

The first is different, since you could also use it if an answer was given, but was not sufficiently clear. The second is different since it is much weaker, it is tacitly agreed that you didn't agree, but you also didn't *disasgree*.

Is there any idiom for *your silence implies your consent*?

Comment: [Qui tacet consentit](http://wordinfo.info/unit/2079/ip:1/il:T)

Comment: No idioms that I can think of, but variations on *silence is/implies consent/agreement/acquiescence* abound.

Comment: Daniel, if you made an answer out of that, I would vote it up!

Comment: Are you looking for something along the lines of "object now, or I assume that you agree", or more "you have not spoken, so you I assume that you agree"?

Comment: Per Daniel's comment: The phrase "tacit consent" pretty much covers the intended meaning. Also, "speak now or forever hold your peace," from the standard wedding ceremony is similar. Jocularly, the auctioneer's "going once, going twice..." can be used conversationally as well.

Comment: @Jim More the latter.

Comment: I will add this as a comment since it is not exactly the same: one phrase used at weddings has become commonly used; *"speak now or forever hold your peace"*.

Comment: I sometimes like to use "speak now or forever hold your piss" and see if they notice ..

Comment: Similar, but slightly different: no news is good news.

Comment: Speak only if opposed.

Comment: French => "Qui ne dit rien, consent".

Comment: We have an idiom in our language, Telugu, which translates to "Silence is half agreement"

Comment: @Danielδ - Nice link you provided - must bookmark it.

Comment: Is "tacit agreement" right? I suspect it may imply more than just staying silent - probably some kind of intentional but nonverbal cue - but I'm not sure.

Comment: The idiom _**Daniel**_ noted is actually a shortened version of the latin _'Qui tacet consentire videtur, ubi loqui debuit ac potuit'_. It has muliple translations, including:
1.  _'He who is silent, when he ought to have spoken and was able to, is taken to agree.'_ 
2.  _'Thus, silence gives consent; he ought to have spoken when he was able to'_.

Apologies for the muck.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I am not sure this qualifies as an idiom, but is a common enough expression: I would express it "unless I hear otherwise".

> Unless I hear otherwise, I am going to leave at 4:00.

Comment: Or "unless someone objects" ... ?

Answer (score 38):

Speak now or forever hold your peace.

Comment: +1 This comes from wedding ceremonies, but is recognized and understood universally (in English).

Comment: @BlueRaja: I doubt the first occurence of *Speak now or forever hold...peace* was in the context of a wedding, but you're right that this is the context we're all familiar with today.

Comment: Probably adding a "May" or "Please" in front would look better? - Please speak now or forever hold your peace ~or~ May speak now or forever hold your peace

Comment: This is too tied to the wedding ceremony. I would be very surprise to see this idiom in a contract, or in oral speech (without implying the reference to the wedding ceremony)

Comment: @rds: on the contrary, I think it is used often, though perhaps a little tongue-in-cheek, in oral communication.

Answer (score 28):

There is a [legal phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acquiescence) '*silence is acquiescence*', which I have seen used somewhat in business.

The trick, in business, is to soften it a bit to show that it is trying to spare someone from being obliged to reply (to an email, for example).

I have used this, as an example:

> Dear team,
>
> I propose that we reboot the server in 5 minutes.
>
> No reply necessary. Silence is acquiescence.

Comment: +1. I've also heard "silence is consent" (which, going by Google, seems to be even more common) and "silence is concurrence" (which seems to be less common).

Comment: [see the NGram for that](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=silence+is+acquiesence%2C+silence+is+consent%2C+silence+is+concurrence%2C+silence+is+agreement&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 17):

It's possible that the word you're looking for is *[tacit](http://www.wordnik.com/words/tacit)*, which means to be understood or implied without being stated.

Answer (score 14):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

> Silence gives consent.

Google it, I believe it's a direct translation of "Qui tacet consentire".

By the way, <strike>German/English</strike> Dutch/English is not the only language that has this phrase. I know for a fact that there is a Russian expression that, translated literally to English, sounds something like: "Silence is a sign of agreement".

Also, here's what Ngram Viewer shows:
[image]

Comment: In Sanskrit, which, like Latin, is a Indo-European language, it is "Maunam Sweekruti Lakshanan" which translates as "Silence is a sign of acceptance".

Comment: It's in classic and modern Hebrew as well. And I believe that the [NGram of this version vs "silence is consent"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=silence+is+consent%2Csilence+gives+consent&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) as per above is even more telling.

Comment: Didn't the same idiom exists in German and Russian, but I know the same idiom exists in Arabic language: Al-Sokoot 'Alamat Al-Ridha, meaning "The silence is the sign of acceptance."

Comment: The French version is "Qui ne dit mot consent". Wiktionary link : http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/qui_ne_dit_mot_consent

Comment: Uhm, where'd you get to German here? "Zwijgen is instemmen" is not, if that was what you referred to

Comment: @TobiasKienzler thanks for correction. It sounded German to me. Google translate detects it as Dutch.

Comment: In fact I don't think the idiom exists in German. The closest you get is "Keine Antwort ist auch eine Antwort" (_no answer is also an answer_), which is almost exclusively used when someone is suspected to have done something bad and, when accused of it, neither confesses nor denies but stays silent. "Keine Antwort ist auch eine Antwort" then concludes that they _have_ done it.

Comment: @DilipSarwate thanks for the sanskrit translation, was actually looking for the same ;)

Answer (score 11):

Sure. There is the phrase, "Silence is consent", sometimes given as "silence implies consent" or "silence is assent".

Comment: More often, and of long standing, is "Silence lends assent".

Comment: Well, I don't recall ever hearing "Silence lends assent", and it rates well below "silence is assent" on Google ngram. Not to say it isn't used.

Answer (score 6):

The phrase "tacit consent" refers to the consent given by the failure to dissent, although that isn't a standalone phrase.  "Speak now or forever hold your peace" is used in the context of weddings, but doesn't get much use elsewhere.

Other than those, simply saying, "Your silence implies your consent" works just fine.

Comment: Taciturn consent?  Surely you mean tacit consent?

Answer (score 5):

"Without objection...". We use this in parliamentary meetings. for example: "Without objection, so ordered." Or "Without objection, it has been moved to table the matter of ..." this is an expedited way of obtaining *unanimous consent* without incurring the delay of formal and explicit agreement.

Comment: I think *nem. con.* is more common, but it means the same.

Answer (score 2):

There was an author of military thrillers that used the term UNODIR for this situation.

It means UNless Otherwise DIRected. The usage was that the character would send a report up the chain of command and end it with "UNODIR I am going to do something crazy and kill the bad guys".

Answer (score 1):

The direct translation of the latin *Qui tacet consentit* that has been thrown around here a few times is "He who is silent consents", but obviously that's not in common colloquial use -- nor, might I point out, is the latin phrase; not among your average English speaker.

In an informal setting, you're more likely to hear "he didn't say no" or "I never heard otherwise", which essentially carries the same meaning but without being a clearly-identifiable saying.